# Making numeric double integration more efficent

Tags: python, optimization, numerical-methods

So i've made a simple program for numerically aproximating double integral, which accepts that the bounds of the inner integral are funcions:

```
def double_integral(func, limits, res=1000):
    t = time.clock()
    t1 = time.clock()
    t2 = time.clock()
    s = 0
    a, b = limits[0], limits[1]
    outer_values = np.linspace(a, b, res)
    c_is_func = callable(limits[2])
    d_is_func = callable(limits[3])
    for y in outer_values:
        if c_is_func:
            c = limits[2](y)
        else:
            c = limits[2]
        if d_is_func:
            d = limits[3](y)
        else:
            d = limits[3]
        dA = ((b - a) / res) * ((d - c) / res)
        inner_values = np.linspace(c, d, res)
        for x in inner_values:
            t2 = time.clock() - t2
            s += func(x, y) * dA
        t1 = time.clock() - t1
     t = time.clock() - t
     return s, t, t1 / res, t2 / res**2
```

This is, however, terribly slow. When `res=1000`, such that the integral is a sum of a million parts, it takes about 5 seconds to run, but the answer is only correct to about the 3rd decimal in my experience. Is there any way to speed this up?

The code i am running to check the integral is

```
    def f(x, y):
        if (4 - y**2 - x**2) < 0:
            return 0              #This is to avoid taking the root of negarive #'s
        return np.sqrt(4 - y**2 - x**2)

    def c(y):
        return np.sqrt(2 * y - y**2)

    def d(y):
        return np.sqrt(4 - y**2)
    # b d
    # S S f(x,y) dx dy
    # a c
    a, b, = 0, 2
    print(double_integral(f, [a, b, c, d]))
```

The integral is eaqual to 16/9

**Edit**

so i got a great answer over at [coderewiev](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188146/numeric-double-integration/188148#188148), but i am still baffeled by how `scipy.integrate.dblquad` seem to give me the wrong answer (see comment). does anyone have an answer for this?

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: Is it the trapezoidal method? First of all, you might try something with more accuracy - some kind of Simpson or maybe even Gauss-Legendre. Your implementation seems pretty straight-forward to me, the nature of this algorithm will require nested loop, so I can't see how you can decrease the running times dramatically, other than write it in C or something like that.

Comment: It is something like the trapezoidal method, only with the function evaluated in the "bottom right" corner of each partition. I am fully aware that it is far from the best method of implementing double integration, it is mostly an exercise. I was more wondering if there is any black numpy magic or something like that to speed it up.

Comment: Can you post the `func`, `limits` and the expected result?

Comment: the function is `sqrt(4 - y**2 - x**2)`, the bounds of the outer integral is 0 to 2, and the bounds for the inner integral is `sqrt(2 * y - y**2)` to `sqrt(4 - y**2)`, which evaluates to 16/9. (1.777 repeating)

Comment: Add it to the question, it will be easier.

Comment: I wasn't able to reduce the runtime drastically. You can shave off tenth of a second here and there, but nothing on the scale of orders of magnitude. The nested loop is probably what's contributing the most to the runtime. I tried to solve your problem with `dblquad` from `scipy`, and it was both much more accurate and lightning fast. You can look into its implementation to see why it's so fast.

Comment: So, i tried `dblquad` on my excample integral, and it actually gives the wrong answer... I checked with several simple integrals without problem, but `dblquad` evaluates my integral to 2.257838806996919, which is really weird.. (I have checked the integral by hand). Does anyone get why this happens?

Comment: `scipy.integrate.dblquad(f, 0, 2, c, d)` gives me `(1.7777777777777701, 1.3374814589184325e-09)`.  Are you sure?